# rotating a single line multiple times in canvas

Tags: rotation, html5-canvas, html5-video, translation, shapes

the code below is almost fine but I want to make it short and simple by using a single makeline() function so as to avoid the repetition of the code lines.
I want the loading image to remain same only I want the code to be short. by using the above-mentioned function. As you can see below the code is too lengthy and when it is run the lines are not properly adjusted.
I want the shape to remain the same the position of the lines should be same only a little bit of adjustment

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <style>
        myCanvas {
            border: 1px;
            background: rgba( 240, 238, 238, 0.898);
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:  ">

</canvas>

    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(470, 470)
        ctx.rotate(15 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(25, 45);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(55 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 35);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 35);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 35);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(50 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(25, 35);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(50 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 35);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(40 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(5 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(15 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 45);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(15 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 45);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(25 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 35);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.moveTo(35, 35);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);

        ctx.stroke();

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sweep A Line

If you are wanting to move the line along its normal (90deg from its direction) and rotate it while doing so the following will explain how to do this using absolute positioning (no `ctx.rotate` calls)

Some utility functions to get started.

```
// A Point also defines a vector.
const Point = (x,y) => ({x,y});
const Line = (p1, p2) => ({p1, p2});
const lengthOfVec = vec => (vec.x ** 2 + vec.y ** 2) ** 0.5;
const normalVec = line => { // normalize the line and return a vector
     const vec = Point(line.p2.x - line.p1.x, line.p2.y - line.p1.y);
     const length =lengthOfVec(vec);
     vec.x /= length;
     vec.y /= length;
     return vec;
}
const rotateVec90 = vec => ([vec.y, vec.x] = [vec.x, - vec.y], vec);
```

We can start with a line defined by its end points `p1` and `p2` and the normal of the line is a vector that is at 90 deg to the left of the line.

We will create a function that moved the line along this normal, the function will also rotate the line as it does, and by the looks of your example the line needs to change length as well so we can add a scale argument as well.

### The steps

The function will be `sweepLine(line, distance, rotate, scale)`, where`rotate` is in radians (I will not use degrees), `distance` is in pixels, `scale > 1` will grow the line and `scale < 1` will shrink the line.

```
function sweepLine(line, dist, rot, scale){
```

We need the center of the line and the line normalised and normal as a vector

```
    const center = Point((line.p1.x + line.p2.x) / 2, (line.p1.y + line.p2.y) / 2);
    const lineNorm = normalVec(line);
    const norm = rotateVec90(Point(lineNorm.x, lineNorm.y));
```

### No rotate

We need the new position of the center, if we are rotating the new center will be at the end of an arc, if not rotating the new position will be at the end of a line. Just move the center along the normal

```
    if(rot !== 0){
         // need the dist of point from center 
         const ax = line.p2.x - center.x;
         const ay = line.p2.y - center.y;

         // move the point
         center.x += norm.x * dist;
         center.y += norm.y * dist;
```

Now we can just scale the line

```
         line.p1.x = center.x - ax * scale 
         line.p1.y = center.y - ay * scale;
         line.p2.x = center.x + ax * scale;
         line.p2.y = center.y + ay * scale;
    }
```

### Rotate moves on an arc

For the rotated line we need to find the point on the arc, and to define an arc we need that arc's center. The length of an arc is the change in angle times the radius, we dont have the radius

```
     else {
         const arcRadius = dist / rot;
```

The arc center is `arcRadius` distance from the center (Note that `rot` can be negative an that will move the center to the correct position)

```
         const arcCenter = Point(
             center.x + lineNorm.x * arcRadius,
             center.y + lineNorm.y * arcRadius
         );
```

now we have the center we need the start angle of the arc, which is the direction of the line.

```
         const startAngle = Math.atan2(lineNorm.y, lineNorm.x);
         const endAngle = startAngle + rot;
```

We add the rotation to the `startAngle` and then move `arcRadius` distance from the `arcCenter` along that new angle to the new center.

```
         center.x = arcCenter.x + Math.cos(endAngle) * arcRadius;             
         center.y = arcCenter.y + Math.sin(endAngle) * arcRadius;
```

With the new position of the center we can change the lines size and rotate it at the same time if we get the length of the line.

```
         const len = lengthOfVec(Point(line.p1.x - line.p2.x, line.p1.y - line.p2.y));

         line.p1.x = center.x - Math.cos(endAngle) * len * scale * 0.5;
         line.p1.y = center.y - Math.sin(endAngle) * len * scale * 0.5;
         line.p2.x = center.x + Math.cos(endAngle) * len * scale * 0.5;
         line.p2.y = center.y + Math.sin(endAngle) * len * scale * 0.5;
```

And that is it. The function can return.

```
    }
}
```

### Example

To show usage example the snippet below does the same but has some optimizations along the way.

The example creates a random line and then moves it using the sweepLine function. It is animated to continuously draw lines.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(update);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
function update(timer){
    if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
        w = canvas.width = innerWidth;
        h = canvas.height = innerHeight;
    }
    jiggle(); 
    sweepLine(line, moveBy,rotateBy, scaleBy);
    drawLine(line);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


// A Point also defines a vector.
const Point = (x,y) => ({x,y});
const Line = (p1, p2) => ({p1, p2});
const lengthOfVec = vec => (vec.x ** 2 + vec.y ** 2) ** 0.5;
const normalVec = line => { // normalize the line and return a vector
     const vec = Point(line.p2.x - line.p1.x, line.p2.y - line.p1.y);
     const length = lengthOfVec(vec);
     vec.x /= length;
     vec.y /= length;
     return vec;
}
const rotateVec90 = vec => {
    const t = vec.x;
    vec.x = - vec.y; 
    vec.y = t;
    return vec;
}




function sweepLine(line, dist, rot, scale){
    const center = Point((line.p1.x + line.p2.x) / 2, (line.p1.y + line.p2.y) / 2);
    const len = lengthOfVec(Point(line.p1.x - line.p2.x, line.p1.y - line.p2.y));
    const lineNorm = normalVec(line);
    const norm = rotateVec90(Point(lineNorm.x, lineNorm.y));
    if(rot === 0){
         const ax = (line.p2.x - center.x) * scale;
         const ay = (line.p2.y - center.y) * scale;
         center.x += norm.x * dist;
         center.y += norm.y * dist;
         line.p1.x = center.x - ax 
         line.p1.y = center.y - ay;
         line.p2.x = center.x + ax;
         line.p2.y = center.y + ay;
    } else {
         const arcRadius = dist / rot;
         const arcCenter = Point(
             center.x - lineNorm.x * arcRadius, center.y - lineNorm.y * arcRadius
         );
         const endAngle = Math.atan2(lineNorm.y, lineNorm.x) + rot;
         var ax = Math.cos(endAngle);
         var ay = Math.sin(endAngle);
         center.x = arcCenter.x + ax * arcRadius;             
         center.y = arcCenter.y + ay * arcRadius;
         const len = lengthOfVec(Point(line.p1.x - line.p2.x, line.p1.y - line.p2.y));
         ax *= len * scale * 0.5;
         ay *= len * scale * 0.5;
         line.p1.x = center.x - ax;
         line.p1.y = center.y - ay;
         line.p2.x = center.x + ax;
         line.p2.y = center.y + ay;
    }
}



function drawLine(line){
    ctx.lineWidth = 8;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";  
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(line.p1.x, line.p1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(line.p2.x, line.p2.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}


function createRandomLine(){
    const x = Math.random() * w * 0.3 + w * 0.35;
    const y = Math.random() * h * 0.3 + h * 0.35;
    const len = Math.random() * 40 + 10;
    const dir = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2; 
    return Line(
        Point(x - Math.cos(dir) * len * 0.5, y - Math.sin(dir) * len * 0.5),
        Point(x + Math.cos(dir) * len * 0.5, y + Math.sin(dir) * len * 0.5)
    );
}


// sweep the line randomly needs some settings
var line, rotateBy, moveBy, scaleBy, col, l = 50,s = 70,hue = 0,moveFor = 0; //
function randomize(){
  rotateBy = Math.random() * 0.5 - 0.25;
  moveBy = Math.random() * 5 + 5;
  scaleBy = 1;
  moveFor = 200; 
  line = createRandomLine();

}
function jiggle(){
   if(moveFor === 0 ){ randomize() }
   rotateBy += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.2;

   scaleBy = Math.random() < 0.2 ? 1/1.1 : Math.random() < 0.2 ?  1.1 : 1;
   moveBy +=  (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
   moveFor --;
   hue = (hue + 1) % 360;
   s = (s + 100  + Math.random() - 0.5) % 100;
   l = (l + 100  + Math.random() - 0.5) % 100;
   col = "hsl("+hue+","+s+"%,"+l+"%)";
}
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Nice animation!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to draw some sort of sun with rays coming out.

Here is one option with much less code than yours, the key is to use a function to do the drawing

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var hw = c.width/2; 
var hh = c.height/2
ctx.translate(hw, hh)
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

function drawLine(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x * hw/3, y * hh/3);
  ctx.lineTo(x * hw, y * hh);
  ctx.stroke();
}

var p200 = Math.PI * 200
for (i = 0; i < p200; i += p200 / 12)
  drawLine(Math.sin(i/100),  Math.cos(i/100));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="170" height="170">
```

---

And with that same function and a few math tricks you can draw some more complex shapes like a sea shell looking shape like this:

[image]

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const p200 = Math.PI * 200

function drawLine(x, y, m) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x * m/3, y * m/3);
  ctx.lineTo(x * m, y * m);
  ctx.stroke();
}    

function shell(ini, end, mid) {
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle="black";
  for (i = ini; i < end; i += p200 / 124)
    drawLine(Math.cos(i/100),  Math.sin(i/100), mid - i/10);

  ctx.translate(-3, -3) 
  ctx.strokeStyle="cyan";
  for (i = ini; i < end; i += p200 / 96)
    drawLine(Math.cos(i/100),  Math.sin(i/100), mid - i/10);

  ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
  for (i = ini; i < end; i += p200 / 48)
    drawLine(Math.cos(i/100),  Math.sin(i/100), mid - i/10);     

  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  ctx.strokeStyle="green";
  for (i = ini; i < end; i += p200 / 48)
    drawLine(Math.cos(i/100),  Math.sin(i/100), mid - i/10);
}


ctx.translate(70, 60) 
shell(0, p200, 95)

ctx.translate(200, 40) 
shell(p200/1.8, p200+p200/1.8, 135)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="340" height="170">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the result, you may write a function like this:

```js
function drawLine(t,r, p1,p2){
//t: translation object 
//r: rotation object
//p1: point  object for the moveTo() method
//p2: point  object for the lineTo() method
    //ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(t.x, t.y)
    ctx.rotate(r * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    //ctx.restore();
}
```

I've commented out the save & restore methods since you don't use them, but those methods are very useful and help you to save a lot of calculations.

Comment: sorry got it ! iwas not specifiying both translate parameters